# Meteor - localizing accounts:ui in a React.js wrapper

Tags: jquery, meteor, reactjs, meteor-blaze, meteor-react

I'm using an accounts:ui wrapper for react, which I'd like to localize (translate to Portuguese). I haven't really worked with Blaze before, so I'm not sure what approach to take. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546972/meteor-accounts-ui-localization) I've seen a trick for Blaze users to localize accounts:ui, it's done by replacing the text after .rendered callback is called. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work with react? I've tried replacing strings with jQuery (with and without delay), but it didn't work.

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
  $('#login-sign-in-link').text('Přihlásit se ▾');
  $('.login-close-text').text('Zavřít nabídku');
  $('.sign-in-text-google').text('Přihlásit se přes Google');
  $('.sign-in-text-facebook').text('Přihlásit se přes FB');
  //etc...
};
```

And here's my react wrapper:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Use Meteor Blaze to render login buttons
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Clean up Blaze view
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }
  render() {
    // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
}
```